# How to fix ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException?

Tags: solr, nutch, ubuntu-18.04

When I'm starting a crawl from Ubuntu Nutch 1.15 with this:
`/usr/local/nutch/bin/crawl --i -s urls/seed.txt crawldb 5`

Then it starts to run and I get this error:

```
ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.<init>(IndexWriters.java:103)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.lambda$get$0(IndexWriters.java:57)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters$$Lambda$9/9190301.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Map.computeIfAbsent(Map.java:957)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.get(IndexWriters.java:57)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:123)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:244)
Caused by: org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
        at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:167)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.<init>(IndexWriters.java:94)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginClassLoader.loadClassFromSystem(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginClassLoader.loadClassFromParent(PluginClassLoader.java:92)
        at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:72)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.getCachedClass(PluginRepository.java:332)
        at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:156)
        ... 9 more
```

I want to index to Solr 7.5

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like an installation, build or setup issue. What do you mean with "Ubuntu Nutch 1.15"?
You may also check the index step separately:  `.../bin/nutch index -Dplugin.includes=indexer-solr <crawldb> <segment>`

Comment: I added the -Dplugin.includes=indexer-solr to the command and it still throw the same error. Ubuntu Nutch 1.15 was just to tell that Ubuntu is installed and that the version of Nutch is 1.15

Comment: If a class is not found something is wrong with the Nutch installation. The missing class should be contained in `/usr/local/nutch/plugins/indexer-solr/indexer-solr.jar`. Can you verify this?

Comment: Yes, of cause you are right, was having the wrong plugin folder, I have added the folder and now I just a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617512/how-to-fix-this-error-running-nutch-1-15-error-fetcher-fetcher-fetcher-job-did

And thank you, @SebastianNagel, for your help!